# I get error when use JQuery in AMP html How to reslove it?

Tags: jquery, amp-html

I have developed Html page using AMP. And I include the JQuery plugin link in amp-script tag, It gives the error like below image. 
[image: enter code here]

Comment: is the script within the size limit set for `amp-script`?

Comment: Thats not an issue we can use it as minify version of js. But I need to use 3rd party js in my code. So far we can't use any 3rd party js or js libraries. We need to build our own.

Comment: I can't quite tell from your screen shotes, so remember - you can't load dependencies. The JS has to be vanilla JS - that works, for example, without dependencies on Playcode (https://playcode.io/online-javascript-editor).